# CustomImageLabelerOptions is missing. Where can I find it?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-mlkit, image-classification

I'm attempting to use a modified version of the google example for image categorization. I've got everything working except for one thing. The CustomImageLabelerOptions class is not found.

I've got

```
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:image-labeling-custom:16.3.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.mlkit:image-labeling:17.0.4'
```

and

```
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
        // or noCompress "lite"
    }
```

in the grade file. I've also added maven appropriately.

Here is the code where I'm trying to use CustomImageLabelerOptions.

```
val cats_dogs_model = LocalModel.Builder().setAssetFilePath("cat_vs_dog.tflite").build()
        val customImageLabelerOptions = CustomImageLabelerOptions.Builder(cats_dogs_model)
                .setConfidenceThreshold(0.5f)
                .setMaxResultCount(5)
                .build()
```

Any ideas why the class is not found?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this dependency `implementation 'com.google.mlkit:image-labeling-custom:16.3.1'` locally and it seems working fine for me.

Did you sync the project after adding `implementation 'com.google.mlkit:image-labeling-custom:16.3.1'` to build.gradle file?

Comment: That did it. I can't believe I missed that one. :)